# How can prefill multiple search columns with their values when returning with stateSave: true?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using the jQuery DataTables plug-in (version 1.10.5) with the `stateSave: true` option and custom multiple column search inputs:

```
$(function(){
    $.fn.extend({
        myDataTable: function(options){
            var $tr = $('<tr></tr>');

            $('thead th', this).each(function(){
                var $td = $('<td></td>')

                var $input = $('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + $.trim($(this).text()) + '" />');

                $td.append($input);

                $tr.append($td);
            });

            $('thead', this).prepend($tr);

            $(this).dataTable(options);

            var table = $(this).DataTable();

            table.columns().eq(0).each(function(colIdx){
                $('input', table.table().header()).eq(colIdx).on('keyup textInput change blur click', function(){
                    table.column(colIdx).search($(this).val()).draw();
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When leaving the page and returning, the filter is correctly applied, but the values entered into the search inputs are gone. How can I have them pre-filled when returning and using `stateSave: true`?

I have tried using the `fnStateLoaded` callback, but I can't find where the filter values for each column are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually came across your question looking for the answer.  A bit more searching and I found the right solution.  Check out https://odoepner.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/jquery-datatables-column-filters-state-saving/ for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick and simple workaround that I have implemented.

Step 1:
Assign unique ID's to each tfoot input so that you can easily identify which inputs have a filter value when saveState is true.

```
var counter = 0;
$('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" id="footer_filter['+counter+']" placeholder="Search '+title+'" value="" />' );
    counter++;
} );
```

Step 2:
Add this function to your datatable:

```
"stateLoaded": function (settings, data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.columns.length; i++) {
        var filter = data.columns[i].search['search'];
        if (filter) {
            var element = document.getElementById("footer_filter["+i+"]");
            element.value = filter;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle for the same:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrdp/jqaoxn1L/12/)

Cheers!